OpenAI API Integration in Django: Request Getting Lost on Server
I have integrated the OpenAI API into my Django project for generating dynamic descriptions for tables generated in my application. The workflow involves processing user input, generating tables, and then passing these tables to the OpenAI API one by one using client.chat.completions.create. While this works smoothly on my local system, when deployed on the server, the request sometimes seems to get lost at the point of calling client.chat.completions.create. It returns the response processed until that stage, rather than waiting for the completion response from the OpenAI API.
try:
    chat_completion = client.chat.completions.create(
        messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
        ],
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        temperature=0.5,   
        max_tokens=1024   
        
    )
    logger.info('---- GPT4')
    logger.info("chat completion",chat_completion.choices[0].message.content) 
    response_content = chat_completion.choices[0].message.content
    logger.info('---- GPT5')
    
except Exception as e:
    logger.info('----  Error in chat gpt "',str(e))
    pass

Upon debugging, it seems that the request doesn't wait for the response from client.chat.completions.create, causing it to return incomplete responses on the server. What could be causing this behavior, and how can I ensure that the request waits for the completion response from the OpenAI API before proceeding further? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Not a complete answer, but maybe this library can simplify the OpenAI + Django integration for you: https://github.com/vintasoftware/django-ai-assistant/
